# How to write a novel with a mixture of horror and crime (detective) thriller?

Tags: novel, book, ideas

I just had a idea where what if A Detective and his buddy have to face supernatural creatures, cases full of mystery... Like two stories : Sherlock Holmes + Goosebumps ( orIT) smashed together into one idea. Would it be possible? I have a detective and his buddy but it's hard to figure out if i have different type of mythic creatures, monsters and ghostly entities. What can i do with them? Their scope to not *kill* them until Chapter 26 or 32? A story where the kids discover the ghosts and the parents don't believe them? Then, when they know the truth. They call the Detectives... Then the detectives do the inspection and investigation but fail several times to catch it or remove the entity. Then, in the Climax, they are somehow successfull? But, i thought about a Haunted Doll...how could i stretch the story to about 20-30 chapters with clever intellectual 100 IQ detective? Its so confusing and mindbogling to me.

Comment: I think such stories exist. Is the supernatural common knowledge in the world you imagine? Is it known to the detective (before he gets into the mystery)?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! You seem to be asking a bunch of different questions about your idea at once, and that's not how this site works. Could you narrow this down to just one specific question that you need help with?

Comment: @towr yes they do. the world is just like ours normal not a fantasy one. The detective is either phoned or mailed about the case i think...

Comment: @F1 Krazy Thank You!! straightaway, i'm confused about the sequence of events in the story or my novel. Which should be the accurate one from d above? I'm also confused about the antagonist... Where we have horror or scary elements but how to add crime and investigative incidents...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occult_detective_fiction

Comment: It's a common genre; lots of classic horror/supernatural fiction has a detective element. But how to structure it is up to you: it's no different to any other detective novel, which will often feature multiple crimes and red herrings.

Comment: While this question seems to ask about what to write, we now have a place where you can suggest your ideas and receive feedback or see how others would tackle your issue. For instance you could suggesting writing two very short stories with the same arc, such that the second one is a horror version of the first one? https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/the-next-writing-challenge-could-be-yours

Comment: Lots of good questions here… As others have said, narrow it down to 1 question at a time, then make it 'generic' so the answers can help other writers too.

Comment: A version of this I particularly like with these two mash-up genres is to make the story start out detective, APPEAR to be really a horror story, and then the real mystery (after getting past the horror red herring) is to find it was a detective/mystery all along (with supernatural characters to give spice). . "Elementary, dear Watson. The butler did it, conspiring with the ghost to pin the whole thing on the werewolf clan."